# Modeling vs photogrammetry for 3d printing a mechanical part?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing, photogrammetry

I want to *automate my blinders with a motor*.

Image added for the motions required.

I somehow need to make the "horn" that attaches the motor to the handle.

Have been thinking of a few possibilities such as **3d printing** or using **clay**.

The problem with 3d printing might be the **constant printing** to *readjust sizes* etc which can be troublesome if you 3d print in a *local business* your pieces, plus the learning curve and dedicated time...

Wonder if photometry could be a feasible answer to the original handle that I could "bool subtract" from the rotatory part.

Has anybody tried photometry for this? Any recommendations in general for what I am trying to achieve?

[image: blinder handle rotation scheme]

Comment: I'd recommend using some kind of measuring tool to get your 3d print as precise as possible. Photogrammetry would likely be too imprecise for this task.

Comment: @NascentSpace so lets say diameter is 3cm. for the hole mesh how much sparing distance would you leave? 3.1cm of hole?

Comment: Try yeggi they may have something...But you have to know your type of blinds.

https://www.yeggi.com/q/automated+blinds/